# Setting Default MVC Action via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am building an application where my routing will depend on the value stored in a cookie.  I want to dynamically grab that cookie value to use as a default action in my RouteConfig.  Is this possible?  Here is my code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = MyJSFile.MyFunc()), id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Where MyFunc gets the cookie value and returns the action name string.  My code is obviously incorrect, I just wrote it to illustrate what I am attempting to do.  Is something like this possible??

Comment: Is `MyJFile.MyFunc` a client-side javascript?  That won't be available server side.  The Action can be called from anywhere, not just your web page - eg fiddler, curl, winform app.  As far as I'm aware, the current routing is a static lookup defined when the application starts and can't run code to determine the action (that would likely be very inefficient when matching multiple routes for every call).  If it did, it would be in the format :  `action = () => foo()` as your current code would assign the result of MyFunc to action when the route is setup (I know it's just example code)

Comment: I think the way I will approach what is suggested here...http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/asp-net-mvc-javascript-routing

Comment: That link isn't asp.net-mvc-routing, it's a way to generate links in javascript files using a whole bunch of extra non-standard configuration.  These "routes" won't work from outside javascript (eg by simply entering the url in the browser) and if this is your solution to the question, then the question should be substantially reworded.

Comment: You can add an `ActionFilter` and redirect to the desired action based on a cookie (but from comment to the answer this also isn't what you want).  It's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> I dont know which method you adopt to read cookies . neither you
>   mention in question so i asume as below..

```
var controller = docCookies.getItem('Mycontroller');
var action = docCookies.getItem('Myaction');
var id = docCookies.getItem('MyID');

window.location.href = "/controller/action/id";
```

> Hope this will help you out

Comment: this works to redirect to a page based on a cookie, however I am actually trying to set the value of a route in my route collection.